# Rest-api with xml response/request design

Tags: xml, rest, jersey

**How are you building and handling/structuring your rest services that responds with XML?** Going away from xml is not in question..

We have rest-api with xml responses (and requests). Our responses can have the structure of

```
<CustomerProfile>
  <Result><ResultCode/><ResultDescription/>
  </Result>
  <Customer/> <!-- Customer data -->
</CustomerProfile>
```

When something goes wrong, we have a ExceptionMapper that builds up that xml with a resultcode and description of the error.

I have the feeling that this limits us.
Since, if I want the service also be able to return another schema as well, lets say multiple customers: CustomersProfile, the mapper would actually not know what object to build.
Unless I have exception handling in my resource, but in my mind the resource should be as dumb as possible.

I would like the service to return a xml response with Customer element only, or Customers.
And if something goes wrong, return a RestException xml element maybe? Such as

```
<RestException>
  <ResultCode/>
  <ResultDescription/>
</RestException>
```

In that way, all our services error handling would handle errors the same way.

One issue though. The client would actually would have the need to have 2 JAXBContexts for normal response and for a general error response. But that could easily be handled.

If you have any nice resource about designing this, please share!